# How to find out the topmost coordinate point where the pixel value got changed in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I have an image. After using Canny Edge detection in OpenCV using the following code I have a binary image with edges detected.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('Test3.jpg')
canny = cv2.Canny(img, 0, 150)
cv2.imshow('Canny Edge', canny)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWdri.jpg)
[Binary Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7MNL.jpg)

Now I want to find out the coordinate value of the point where the pixel value get changed, scanning image from top to bottom. How to do that??

Comment: How should you handle pixels on the same row? Which one should be the one selected? And what do you mean by "changed"? The binary image only shows edges and is generated from the canny output..

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "value get changed". You are creating a new image from an existing one, using a certain algorithms. Do you seek the coordinate of the topmost contour pixel?

Comment: Circle corner, or rectangle corner?

Comment: Iterate each row from top and break when first row is found with any single white pixel, then find the position of that pixel in that row to get the coordinates of desired point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find non-zero pixels, you can use the `numpy` function `nonzero`:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]])
coords = np.nonzero(x)
print(coords)
```

In your case, simply call `np.nonzero(canny)`.

would output

```
array([0, 1, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 0, 1]))
```

You can then query the min/max coordinate value in any dimension, e.g.

```
np.max(coords[0])
```

Comment: I wanted to find out the topmost/global maxima (coordinate) points. Not as exact answer as I was expecting.  However this also helped to solve my problem. Thanks.